# Delete VMDK file with powershell/powercli command?

Tags: powershell, vsphere, powercli, vcenter, vmdk

I'm a little bit stuck because I would like to delete some VMDK file from vSphere with a PowerShell or PowerCLI command.

I know how to do that from the vSphere vCenter GUI but I didn't find how to do that with a command.

Do you think that there is a way to do that with something like:

```
Remove-Item path/to/my/VMDK
```

If someone has already made this, can you show me how?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `vmstores` PSDrive option that will allow you to use standard PowerShell functionalities alongside an authenticated vSphere session.

Example of polling your available datastores:

```
dir -Recurse -Path vmstores:\
```

Additional info: [Browse datastores using PowerCLI](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-PowerCLI-Discussions/Browse-datastores-using-PowerCLI/m-p/2174993/highlight/true#M71411)

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the vmdk file  with the powercli [Remove-Harddisk](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/e7c1a32c-a3c6-4d7c-91bb-18a86a38daf7/12353298-ce6e-4d3f-bd8d-ab9f5ab044cc/doc/Remove-HardDisk.html) cmdlet (with -DeletePermanently you physically remove the vmdk from the datastore).